# Rails 1.2 "service is deprecated"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated

My app is on rails 1.2.6 and I wish to upgrade it to 2.2
I see this warning in the logs:
DEPRECATION WARNING: service is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 2.0  See http://www.rubyonrails.org/deprecation for details. (called from .... application.rb:14)

The line is question is 
service :notification

Can somebody tell me what service does as I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`service` was a way of specifying controller dependencies.  Dependency loading got moved into ActiveSupport.

From the 1.2.0 code:

```
  # Specifies a variable number of services that this controller depends on. 
  # Services are normally singletons or factories, like
  # Action Mailer service or a Payment Gateway service.
  def service(*services)
    require_dependencies(:service, services)
    depend_on(:service, services)
  end
  deprecate :service
```

Comment: So I simply remove this line and it will work or do I need to do something extra?

Comment: I believe just removing it will work.  But I can't make any promises w/o seeing more of your code.